# Constructing an injection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For any non-empty set A, construct an injection $ f: A \to P(A)$

How do I create an injection for this case

Do I show the power set equals to the elements in set A?

Comment: $a\longmapsto\{a\}$ is one such injection.

Comment: @Bernard how would i prove it just in case

Comment: See [Injective function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function): "In mathematics, an injective function or injection is a function that preserves distinctness: it never maps distinct elements of its domain to the same element of its codomain. In other words, every element of the function's codomain is the image of at most one element of its domain."

Comment: The injectivity? At which condition do you think one has $\{a\}=\{b\}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the easiest one defined by

$$(\forall a\in A) \;\;\;\; f (a)=\{a\}. $$

for $a,b\in A $,

$$f (a)=f (b)\implies \{a\}=\{b\}$$
$$\implies a=b $$

this proves $f $ is injective.